# how to rewrite code using tail recursion

Tags: ocaml

I just looking for a little advice, how to rewrite code using tail recursion

```
open Core.Std;;

let rec dig x =
    match x with
    | 0 -> []
    | _ -> x :: dig (x - 1)
;;


let () = 
    let numbers = dig 10 in
    List.iter ~f:(Printf.printf "%d, ") numbers;
    Printf.printf "\n";
;;
```

Any advice will be helpful

Answer (score 3):

```
let dig x =
    let rec f x s =
        match x with
        | 0 -> s
        | _ -> f (x-1) (x::s)
    f x []
```

Is this what you want? It's using tail recursion.

Edit:
for a decreasing seq,  just replace (x::s) with (List.append s [x]) or (s @ [x]) but it's NOT a good idea,and  List.rev is better:

```
let dig x =
    let rec f x s =
        match x with
        | 0 -> s
        | _ -> f (x-1) (s @ [x])
    f x []
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. Your function makes increasing sequence, but I'm trying create decreasing sequence.

Comment: You should reverse the result with `List.rev` to preserve the order

Answer (score 1):

```
let dig x =
  let rec f s z =
    if z = x then s
    else f (z::s) (z+1)
  in
  f [] 0
```

not sure if this floats your boat: You may have to tweak the border cases depending if you want 0 or the starting number included.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `List.rev` after building the list backwards (which in my opinion is perfectly fine), nor starting your recursion with `0` instead of `n`, you can use some kind of continuation:

```
let dig2 x =
  let rec aux x kont =
    match x with
     | 0 -> kont
     | _ -> aux (x-1) (fun l -> kont (x::l))
in
aux x (fun l -> l) [];;
```

Basically each step returns a function that, given the list built by the remaining steps, will append `x` to it. We start the recursion with the identity function since we don't have anything to build yet. Then, when we exit from the recursion, we thus just have to apply the empty list to the obtained function.

Comment: You know, it's not  I don't like solution with List.rev or inner recursive function, I just trying to find more ways for solving this simple task. I only start learning OCaml and want to see, how other uses it on simple tasks. (And the same thing I can say about my English learning).

Comment: That's fine with me. I just wanted to stress out the fact that the first two answers were more idiomatic than mine, which is indeed merely here for the sake of completeness.

Comment: "you can use some kind of continuation" also known as `Difference Lists`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to can have multiple solutions

```
open Core.Std;;


let rec digtail ?(l=[]) x =
    match x with
    | 0 -> l
    | _ -> digtail ~l: (l @ [x]) (x - 1)
;;


let () = 
    let numbers = digtail 10 in
    List.iter ~f:(Printf.printf "%d, ") numbers;
    Printf.printf "\n";
;;
```

Thanks to all, you helped a lot.

Comment: `l@[x]` makes your function quadratic instead of linear: for each call, you're traversing the whole `l` built so far for appending a single element. In addition `@` itself is not tail recursive, thus you're in fact shifting your issue from `digtail` to `@`. You really should prefer Syeerzi's solution (with the final `List.rev` suggested by ivg)